# How to change MS Sql server Date format change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I create a DB after changing my System date time format from d/M/yyyy to M/d/yyyy then I query `Select getdate()` if return dateformat in M/d/yyyy. Then I change my System date format change and again fire that query again but result is same.  But I want to change date format by fire any sql query ***with out convert function use***.

Comment: A date does not have an inherent format, and it doesn't help to think of it as having one. Don't worry about the format in which SSMS displays the date by default, when passed to the presentation layer it is just a date, that can still be formatted however you like. And I cannot stress this enough, this is where all formatting should occur, **not** within SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the datetime from your local machine you will need to use

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
```

[`Read here`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) to learn more about `SYSDATETIME()` function.

but the format will always be format of datetime Datatype.

To get it in any other format you will need to convert it or cast it as a string and then format it the way you want it to be. in datetime datatype the format is always `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`

Comment: I don't want to use function. I have to change in Data-Base dateformat format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different Date time formats in sql.For eg: I used 101

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) AS Yourdate
```

See this link..
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you are bette off changing the SQL default dateformat, if the formart you want is wrong:

check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx